# Hibernate is not creating tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have been trying to make a table automatically with hibernate. Tried all the solutions given for the same question.  Please have a look and point out what is wrong. I am using it with MySQL 5.6  version.

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("com/hibernate.hbm.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println(factory.toString() + " - DONE");
    }
}
```

Product class is :

```
public class Product
{
    private String product;

    private String productName;

    public String getProduct()
    {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product)
    {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getProductName()
    {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName)
    {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
}
```

My hbm file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com">
    <class name="Product" table="product_table">
        <id name="product" column="product_id" type="java.lang.String" length="20" >
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="productName" column="product_name" type="java.lang.String" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And hibernate.cfg.xml is given below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/caching_hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="cache.providerclass">org.hibernate.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <mapping resource="com/product.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Program shows no exception and runs normally..Thanks in advance

Comment: hibernate code is not supported behave in such situation.

Comment: Try `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` with value `create-drop` or `create`

Comment: Code of Product class can help.

Comment: Update will create tables if not present,Did you created Database/schema?

Comment: @Peter... tried create-drop and crate. Not working here

Comment: @mahesh... Yeah I have created caching_hibernate explicitely

Comment: @RomanC... Which situation you are talking about ? Please clarify

Comment: @eRRor404... Added Product class. Please have a look.

Comment: Any other suggestions. Code still not working. Tried all above suggestions.

Comment: Problem resolved. It was with dialect. I was using org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect but in my case with MySQL-5.6 org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect worked. +5 for me. LOL

Comment: @ALEN This cant be the problem. They are compatible. But if you wrote its resolved... i would suggest you need a `.openSession()`.

Comment: @PeterRader... Tried your suggestion. I opened session from sessionFactory. But same result. Table didn't get created. But as far as compatibility goes, this compatibility doesn't seem to working here.

Comment: @PeterRader... Now tables is created with UPDATE. I think it doesn't even require CREATE until table is absent in database.